# Template specialization in class

Tags: c++, templates

In specific class,

It is working..

```
private:
template <typename U>
int64_t parseValue(const std::string& str
        , typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, U>::type* = 0
        ) const
{
    return stoll(str, 0, base_);
}

template <typename U>
uint64_t parseValue(const std::string& str
        , typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, U>::type* = 0
        ) const
{
```

but the code below does not work. I do not know why. I do not know if there is a lack of specialization concepts or other problems.

```
private:
template <typename U>
int64_t parseValue(const std::string& str
        , typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>::type* = 0
        ) const
{
    return stoll(str, 0, base_);
}

template <typename U>
uint64_t parseValue(const std::string& str
        , typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type* = 0
        ) const
```

It is not working.

Could you explain? I don't know why..

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? I can guess why it doesn't work, but without a complete example, it would be just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are not using `U` in the `enable_if` statements. SFINAE only works if the expression depends on one of the **deduced** template parameters.

Comment: I don't understand perfectly. thanks.